# How to set NavigationController navigationItem title from ViewController loaded by Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've a `UIViewController` which loads it's view form a Xib file. In my `AppDelegate.m` I would like to initiate my rootViewController with that myViewController and I would like that the title of the navigtionItem is set by taking the `NavigationBar` view which is part of the Xib file of the myViewController:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

> Each time the top-level view controller changes, the navigation controller updates the navigation bar accordingly.

In my setup this seems not to happen or I haven't indicated that my `NavigationBar` view is actually the navigationBar to consider.

How can I tell the NavigationController to update it's navigationItem content (title, left and right bar buttons) according the `NavigationBar` view which is part of the Xib file from myViewController?

**Update**

My Xib layout looks like this:

[image: Xib layout]

I know I can set those items in code by:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = ...;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...;
```

But I want them do design in the Xib file of the ViewController and they should be used in the NavigationController.

Comment: Generally, I would assign `self.navigationItem.titleView`, `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, etc., in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Did you add a `NavigationBar` view to the `UIView` in the xib? If so, that is not how it works. You need to actually add `UINavigationItem` to the controller in the xib. And then you also need to initialise the controller with the nib of course.

Comment: @ ChrisLoonam thanks for the hint. This isn't was I'm looking for. See my update. @Rengers yes that's what I did and I want. I added UINavigationItem within the NavigationBar. See updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a UINavigationBar view to the main UIView doesn't do what you think it does. It merely adds a navigation bar view there in the view, it does not tie into the UINavigationController.

If you use a storyboard, you can add the [`UINavigationItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621851-navigationitem?language=objc) as a child of the `UIViewController`. But since you are not using a storyboard, the easiest way to do it is to update the `navigationItem` in `viewDidLoad`.

---

Sidenote: Apple does not recommend using `viewDidLoad` to setup the navigation item. If you really want to do it the proper way, you can for example do it in the `navigationItem` getter.

```
- (UINavigationItem*)navigationItem
{
  // get super navigation item
  UINavigationItem *navItem = [super navigationItem];

  // do stuff 

  return navItem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you point me to the link where Apple recommends to setup the `navigationItem` in the getter?

Comment: The only thing they say is: "Avoid tying the creation of bar button items in your navigation item to the creation of your view controller's view. The navigation item of a view controller may be retrieved independently of the view controller's view. (...)"

Answer (score 3):

In `ViewWillAppear` method in your ViewController set-

```
      self.navigationItem.title = @"Title name";
```

Also in the same way you can `set self.navigationItem.leftBarButton` and RightBarButton items